# Nanopb get string from pb_ostream_t

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I am using [nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/nanopb/) so I can implement protobuf with some small, cross compiled code.  I have the base of it working but would like to get the encoded protobuf message as a string for sending via UDP (on another system).  Normally with the full blown protobuf library you do something like `message.serializeToString()`.  Nanopb doesn't seem to have that, but surely it's a common thing to do.  The examples given from nanopb use their pb_ostream_t struct and [pb_ostream_from_buffer()](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/nanopb/docs/reference.html#pb-ostream-from-buffer) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a binary string is just an uint8_t array. (Note that a normal C string cannot contain binary data so it cannot be used to store protobuf messages.)

So the pb_ostream_from_buffer() is the correct way to get the result as a "string".

Taking from the [simple.c example](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.c):

```
uint8_t buffer[128];
pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
status = pb_encode(&stream, SimpleMessage_fields, &message);
```

After that the encoded message is in `buffer` and has length of `stream.bytes_written`. That is the string you want.

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying about a "normal C string cannot contain binary data".  Is that not what the standard protobuf serializeToString() is doing?

Basically I want to export the "string" back to another system which will then send it via UDP.

Comment: @ChuckClaunch If you are referring to serializeToString() in the C++ protobuf library, it serializes to a C++ string, which can indeed contain binary data. A C string is null-terminated, and cannot contain null bytes so it cannot contain binary data. Nanopb is a C library, thus it does not serialize directly to C++ strings (though writing your own wrapper is relatively straightforward).

Comment: Ahh, yes that makes sense now.  I did end up solving my issue by just passing the the uint8_t array back out and letting the user code handle the sending with that.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @jpa I there any standard way to send encoded message as a string? I ended up converting to string contains hex numbers but it gets a double size for the buffer.

Comment: @MasoudR. Reading your other question, it seems your main trouble is the 0 bytes in the binary data. Trying to avoid them by any encoding (e.g. base64, cobs) always increases the size of the data.